# N уже определен в N.obj

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс `Application`, хранящий в себе список указателей на `GameObject`. (На самом деле на классы, наследованные от него). Мне нужно сделать глобальный класс/структуру/пространство имен Content, хранящее все аудио файлы, изображения, шрифты и прочее. Компилятор выдает ошибку: "N уже определен в `Tileset.hpp`". Я подключаю "`Content.h`" в `Application.cpp`, чтобы вызвать метод `Load`; во всех `.cpp` файлах с классами-наследниками от `GameObject`.

Моя реализация Content:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
    
namespace Content {
    extern std::string CONTENT = "Content/";
    extern std::string IMAGE = "Image/";
    
    extern void Load();

    extern sf::Texture texture_tileset_1;
    extern sf::Sprite sprite_tileset_1;
};
```

Comment: Как только вы указываете значение, так сразу объявление превращается в определение...

Comment: черт возьми, а ведь точно